# Recursive Maclaurin expansion of ODE solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider the initial value problem

$\cases{y'(x)=xy(x)+2,\\ y(0)=3}$.

Give a recursive formula for the coefficients of the Maclaurin series of a solution $\varphi$ of the above initial value problem.

---

I've tried to establish some recursive rule by which the derivaties of $\varphi$ form and obtained that $\varphi'(0)=2,\varphi''(0)=3,\varphi'''(0)=4,\varphi^{(4)}(0)=9,\varphi^{(5)}(0)=16$ and $\varphi^{(6)}(0)=45$ which doesn't look as if they form recursively, even if we consider $\frac{\varphi^{(i)}(0)}{i!}$.

Comment: Try letting $y(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$. Then substitute this into the differential equation and equate coefficients of like powers of $x$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thanks, that does indeed work.